# Deleting a table view row with Swift 3 and CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to implement swipe to delete a table view cell in my app and I'm getting a crash:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I have my ViewController, and in the ViewControllerDataSource file, I'm conforming to `UITableViewDataSource`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext, editingStyle == .delete else { return }

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Meditation> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meditation")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let sessions = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as [Meditation] {
        managedObjectContext.delete(sessions[indexPath.row])

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        fetchEntries {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

This is what `fetchEntries` looks like

```
func fetchEntries(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        else { return }

    var arrayOfEntries: [Entry] = []
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Meditation> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meditation")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    if let objects = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as [Meditation] {
        meditationSessions = objects

        for (index, object) in objects.enumerated() {
            // set some values that correspond to visual elements in the cell

            let timeLabel = lengthMinutesLabel(minutesString: lengthMinutes(object.length))

            let entry = Entry(
                sessionLength: lengthMinutes(object.length),
                sessionTimeUnit: timeLabel,
                sessionStartTime: "\(object.date.format())",
                sessionJournalEntry: object.journalEntry,
                sessionStreakTop: showStreak.top,
                sessionStreakBottom: showStreak.bottom
            )

            arrayOfEntries.append(entry)
            self.arrayOfEntries = arrayOfEntries
        }
    }

    completion?()
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here that's causing this crash. Unfortunately there's no completion block for the CoreData delete functionality if the crash is caused by a race condition.

I've tried a variety of different orders of operations for the last 7-9 lines of the `tableView:editingStyle:` function to no avail. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete data in coreData it wont be saved by coreData unless you save the action. The delete action should be like this..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .delete {
    managedObjectContext.delete(sessions[indexPath.row])
    do {
      try managedObjectContext.save()
      tableView.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you always just use the same managed object context (which seems the case here, see call to `appDelegate.managedObjectContext`), this shouldn't matter, because I suppose `numberOfRows` / `numberOfSections` will also use it, so it should be consistent independend of saving or not.

Comment: This is the piece I was missing Ganesh. Thanks. @Andreas, one thing you may be touching on is, if I have 2 sessions and I delete both, it crashes on the 2nd deletion. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Zack what do you mean by "sessions" and where do you delete twice?

Comment: sessions = entries. meditation session in the case of my app. 2 cells in the table view. swipe to delete the first, works fine. swipe to delete the second, crashes on tapping 'delete'

Comment: @GaneshKumar almost, still have the crash described in the comment above

Comment: @ZackShapiro first issue solved? what was causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, adding .save() fixed it

Comment: @ZackShapiro if your issue solved, you should accept the answer that solved your problem

Answer (score 5):

> Updated for swift 3:

if you want to delete UITableView row/cell when you are working with Core Data, used below lines of code:

```
import CoreData
```

**// MARK:- Variable Declarations**

```
@IBOutlet weak var mTableView: UITableView!
var manageObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var eventArray = [Event]()  // Where **Event** is an model name
```

**// MARK:- ViewController LifeCycle Methods**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manageObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    self.loadSaveData()
}
```

**// To delete Particular cell/row from tableview**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let eventArrayItem = eventArray[indexPath.row]

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        manageObjectContext.delete(eventArrayItem)

        do {
            try manageObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error While Deleting Note: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    self.loadSaveData()
}
```

**// MARK:- Instance Methods**

```
func loadSaveData()  {

    let eventRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()
    do{
        eventArray = try manageObjectContext.fetch(eventRequest)
        self.mTableView.reloadData()
    }catch
    {
        print("Could not load save data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer is helpful but it gives me error when i delete more than half of cells /

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is cased by the "additional" call to `tableView.reloadData()`.  As long as you call `tableView.deleteRows`, you shouldn't call `reloadData` - so either call the one or the other, maybe dependend of if you want a fade animation (`deleteRows`) or not.

Comment: It wasn't the reason for the crash but definitely a nice addition to know. Thanks Andreas

Comment: that's why i didnt put **deleteRows** method

Comment: deleteRows is a better user experience, esp since it calls tableView.reloadData() as well